# How to face competition with a new coworker at the same position

Tags: career-development, promotion

TLDR; A new (more experienced coworker) has been hired, how to keep a vision on my career in the company?

I joined a software company one year and a half ago as a developer. While the company was in very bad shape, I diagnosed a lack of project (and product) management.
I asked my CTO to promote me as a project manager to solve the situation, even though he was not happy with this, the rest of the board approved.

Some months later, we are now able to deliver and some majors customer signed. The board thanked my work and increased my salary, even suggested to update my job title (still a Developer).

However few days ago my manager came with a "good news" that they hired an experienced project manager in order to "help me".

Somehow, it's seems good for the company but I feel stopped in my progress. Also considering that the company is slowly growing and we start speaking about opening middle manager position (for which I expected to apply).

Is there a way to secure my progress/promotion as a project manager in this company?

EDIT:
I don't want to be back in my developer chair, I'm happy with my new role. Plus in the environment I'm, after graduation, even if you learned PM, you most always start in the dev team, and progress as a PM after years of development (my case).

The main issue is, there is not enough work for two in this job position (and will no be two seat for the middle management position).
And thus I'm a bit disapointed  by this decision of not having preferred my work.
I guess there is no better solution than just talk about this to my boss, have his feeling on the decision. Express mine, And still keeping to do my best.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Do you want to to do more project management work and you won't be able to now? Was the CTO unhappy with you being project manager because he wanted you do development?

Comment: Yeah, not seeing the issue here. Most developers would be happy to step back  into a Project Lead role or up into a CIO role - I did not learn programming to be a project manager. Definitely needs more focus and an idea what the problem is and what the wished career is.

Comment: I think you mean "competition" in your subject title. "Concurrence" has a different meaning in English to what I assume is your native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to keep in mind here. One is that you won't compete with a new hire. They will succeed or fail on their own and on whether the company has enough work to keep them busy. Some companies hire in advance of getting work and this might be what is going on. Or, this person might be a total waste of air. I saw one "project manager" who never comprehended what was going on. She simply was filling out the forms with the information she got in the meetings and published graphs, etc. It may happen that you totally out perform this "project manager".

Two: your project management skills will be very handy in moving forward no matter what happens. They will help you deal with incompetent managers, "death march" projects, and other things common to software development.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess there is no better solution than just talk about this to my boss, have his feeling on the decision. Express mine, And still keeping to do my best.

This sounds like a bad idea for a couple of reasons. One is you're going to express that you don't approve of the new hire because you feel it is a threat to your job. Second, you're assuming a lot of things and that is not a good idea to approach your boss with a lot of assumptions about the new hire. You're going to go in there and tell him that you feel a) The new hire is a threat to your job, b) you don't have a lot of work that can be split between the two (as if it is your choice on how new projects will be balanced), and c) you're telling your boss that you might not corporate with the new hire because you feel he/she is a threat to your job. You're also going in there to tell your boss that this is all your idea and you should have ownership of how it's going to go moving forward. That's not a super great idea since you're basically at the bottom of the ladder. Bad idea overall.

> I asked my CTO to promote me as a project manager to solve the situation, even though he was not happy with this, the rest of the board approved.

> Some months later, we are now able to deliver and some majors customer signed. The board thanked my work and increased my salary, even suggested to update my job title (still a Developer).

This sounds like a major advancement both for you and your company. Perhaps your company figured that since you're taking on everything that they need to split the project.

Personally I would just assume the best for now until you're told otherwise. At this point you are just assuming a lot of things, and they're all negative. I would just continue doing what you're doing and if you're noticing that you're taking on less PM roles, and you don't like that, then you can bring it up with your manager that you want to continue doing PM roles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it complete well the David R. answer.